# In MacOS terminal, is it possible to go back to the previous directory (Multiple times). (e.g. like cd - but going back multiple times)

Tags: linux, macos, unix, terminal, cd

I know I can use `cd -` to go back to the previous location. Is there any way to do this multiple times?

If I try this again it toggles back to the next location - useful, but would be great if I could also keep using a command to move back (not up) the directories I have been in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pushd` and `popd` commands to maintain a stack of visited directories. Example:

```
[~]$ mkdir -p x/y/z
[~]$ pushd x
~/x ~
[~/x]$ pushd y
~/x/y ~/x ~
[~/x/y]$ pushd z
~/x/y/z ~/x/y ~/x ~
[~/x/y/z]$ popd
~/x/y ~/x ~
[~/x/y]$ popd
~/x ~
[~/x]$ popd
~
[~]$
```

Comment: can I just push the pwd?

Comment: Found it - pushd .

Comment: @Blingers Yes, you can. Play with the commands to prime your intuition about them.

Answer (score 0):

Before issuing a **cd**, if you enter into a subshell by issuing **sh**, **bash** or whatever, and then run **cd**, when you will exit from this subshell, you will return to the directory where you were before, and this recursively.